# eval not working in vim with xdebug debugger

Tags: vim, xdebug

Using the vim xdebug debugger, when I am on a breakpoint, then I type ,e then something like `print_r($var, TRUE);`, `$var` content should be printed in the window but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the [Vdebug](https://github.com/joonty/vdebug) plugin, it's working perfectly fine under the same conditions.